# How to remove HTML tags from BLOB field using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using Opencart on one of my sites and I use MySQL to retrieve some fields. One of them is BLOB and the content is something like :

```
"<p>SOME TEXT HERE</p>".
```

The MySQL syntax I use is shown below :

```
$query_desc = mysql_query("SELECT description FROM product_description WHERE product_id = $id_produs AND language_id = 2");
    while($row_desc = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_desc)) {
        $desc = $row_desc['description'];
    }
```

What I am trying to do is remove the HTML tags, but using strip_tags or str_replace doesn't work.

I also tried using SELECT CONVERT but that failed also. Any suggestions?

Comment: hmm... `strip_tags` should work, are you sure that the content of `$desc` is not urlencoded or something? try `var_dump` on `$desc`

Comment: You are supposed to Sanitize the Data before the insertion, but as @Khôi stated... strip_tags should do the work

Comment: This is what I get from var_dump : string(335) "<p> Aceasta rochie face parte din colectia MOJA ATTITUDE. Este un model scurt, fara maneci. Rochia este realizata din clini ce ii ofera acesteia o forma de balon. Sistemul de inchidere este pe baza de fermoar, montat pe spate. In jurul decolteului rotund, la baza gatului sunt montate manual tinte metalice rotunde.</p> "

Comment: Could it have something to do with the column type in MySQL? Or something about a special encoding of it?

Comment: Very unlikely. `var_dump` shows you how PHP internally handles the data. In this case it is handled as PHP string. Please show us the code where you actually use `strip_tags`?

Comment: Off topic, but important: Please note that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are considered obsolete and insecure. They are no longer being maintained and are in the process of being deprecated. The PHP manual **strongly** recommends switching to using either `mysqli_xx()` functions or the PDO library instead.

Comment: I switched to mysqli and get the same results. Below is the code I use with strip_tags :

$query_desc = "SELECT description FROM product_description WHERE product_id = $id_produs AND language_id = 2";
  if ($result_desc = $mysqli->query($query_desc)) {
       while ($row_desc = $result_desc->fetch_assoc()) {
       $desc = strip_tags($row_desc['description']);
      }
  }

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using html_entity_decode on the variable.
The problem originated somewhere in OpenCart, will try to find out where exactly!

If anyone else finds a problem like this, just html_entity_decode your strings and you can use str_replace, strip_tags or preg_replace after and it works fine.